# How to get foreign key by sending primary key in mVC?

Tags: sql, model-view-controller

I am working on mini project in MVC in which I am performing CRUD operations.
I have 3 tables:
Employee: PK: EmpID
Salary: Fk: EmpID
Images: Fk: EmpID
I am navigating between two html pages and passing PK from one.html to two.html.
I want to access the data of Salary and Images table on two.html, I have primary key of Employee table and it is foreign key in rest two tables.

I want to read all data attached to EmpID that is treated as FK in Salary and Images table.
EmpID has only one row in Employee table (PK)
EmpID has multiple rows in Salary and Images table (FK)

Thank You in advance

Comment: You need to learn `JOIN` for this. here is a link:-https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: I created table that satisfy all conditions of PK and FK

Answer (score 1):

```
var employeeImages = _dbContext.Images.Where(i => i.EmpID == 21).ToList();
```

where `21` is the employee id parameter you received in your action method.

Similarly you can query for salaries like:

```
var employeeSalaries = _dbContext.Salaries.Where(i => i.EmpID == 21).ToList();
```

Or both things in the same call:

```
var employee = _dbContext.Employee.Where(e => e.Id == 21).Include(e => e.Images).Include(e => e.Salaries).ToList();
```

If you are working on a production application, calling `DbContext` directly from your controller is not a good idea. You might also want to look at [EF's documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee712907(v=vs.113).aspx).

Also, when you are working at the controller layer, don't think about those in terms of FKs and PKs. Those are just domain models. Think about these in terms of identifiers. FK and PKs only come into the game once we reach the database level (which shouldn't be the controller at the very least).

Comment: Don't you think OP need to learn `JOIN` for this. here is a link:-https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: Might be the case. :) But it's mentioned that OP is having problem with navigation from one.html to two.html.

Comment: I am passing an ID in URL and connecting to controller, it working fine. but 21 is getting as primary key for Salary table where I want 21 should be treated as FK for Salary table so that I can able to get 10-12 rows from database.

Comment: I still don't understand what's your question. I think I might have to agree with @AlivetoDie, you need to read about SQL a bit. 

In SQL, you can always apply filters like SELECT * FROM SALARY WHERE EmpID = whatEverEmployeeIdYouReceive. But if you want to fetch all the data in a single call, you might want to look into JOINs. 
I am not exactly sure about your problem here, but it should be a LEFT JOIN (Employee - Salary - Image).

Comment: From two.html I am calling to controller of Salary table and it has GET of URL "api/SpecificationDetails/ID" where ID is PK for Salary table but the value I am sending to the controller is FK for Salary Table. I am looking for C# code of controller where I can pass the PK of Employee table as FK for Salary and Images table

Comment: I do not want query of SQL, I have EF model loaded in my MVC project.

Comment: @RuchiTang I have edited the answer. Hope it solves your problem. Also, try to be as specific as possible in your question.

Comment: @RuchiTang Please read about Entity Framework as well. EF is an ORM (Object Relational Mapper). It uses the same SQL to talk to the database (given that you are working with a relational DB). So understanding SQL is essential for working with EF.